# Save and display images offline android

Tags: android, list, sqlite

I created an application that is web based. How do I save the content in SD card or internal memory for offline view. (particularly images)?

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific if you want someone to help you.

Anyway, here are some libraries which might be helpful.

- [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) - A powerful image downloading and caching library for Android
- [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) - A type-safe HTTP client for Android and Java

Comment: I tried Picasso. It does not save images to SD card or internal memory. It only helps me to load images to an image view.

Comment: According to [documentation](http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.html#with-android.content.Context-) it does. Check javadoc for `with` method. Investigate documenation and you'll find what you need. If you are expecting those images to be available in local Gallery application, then it does not cache it like that.